# MySQL: Load row-based data into object with 1 MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to load a customer from WooCommerce (WordPress) into a object but WooCommerece uses rows to store both the data and the name / identifier of the data.

From Joomla I am used to just selecting columns to get the information. So my SQL got at bit longer when working with WooCommerce because I had to use some PHP.

It is working but can someone tell me if I somehow can make it into 1 SQL query instead of using PHP at the end?

```
$query = "
SELECT 
    meta_key, meta_value
FROM 
    wp_postmeta
WHERE 
    post_id = ".$order->order_id;

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadRowList();
$result = new stdClass();

if (!empty($rows)) {
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_customer_user")) {
        $result->customer_id = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_first_name")) {
        $result->name = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_last_name")) {
        $result->name = $result->name . " ".$row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_company")) {
        $result->company = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_address_1")) {
        $result->address = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_address_2")) {
        $result->address = $result->address. "\n" . $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_postcode")) {
        $result->postalcode = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_city")) {
        $result->city = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_country")) {
        $result->country = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_email")) {
        $result->email = $row[1];
    }

    if (!empty($row[0] == "_billing_phone")) {
        $result->phone = $row[1];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a single sql query, so I do not really understand your question!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is saving the things different than most systems.
Objects in other systems represent a whole row of one table with many attributes (cols). In WordPress attributes are saved as many rows in a table with much less cols where the first col is the attribute-name and the second one the attribute-value.
So for one row of another system in WordPress you get a whole bunch of rows and the logical combination depends only on the system (WP) but not on database-design. Therefore I don't see a way how to solve your question just by sql.